# Declare template<typename T> once for multiple class or functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I don't know if this question makes any sense; I have several public methods of a generic type class.

```
template <typename T>
bool className<T>::isEmpty() const {
    return root == nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
className<T>::className() {
    root = nullptr;
    ...............
}

template <typename T>
treeNode<T>* className<T> :: routine(treeNode<T>* node) {
    .............
    .............
}
```

I had to write `template<typename T>` every time I implemented a method. This is an unnecessary redundancy. Is there any way to write `template<typename T>` once and use it for all methods like -

```
template<typename T>
void className<T>:: func1() {
     ............
}
void className<T>:: func2() {
     ............
}
void className<T>:: func3(T const& param) {
     ............
}
// somehow ending template<typename T> scope or no need to end as writing 
// another template<typename T> will vanish previous effect
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. If you don't want the extra typing, put your function definitions inside the class definition, particularly for trivial-to-implement functions like `isEmpty()` or the default constructor.

Comment: You may define methods inside a class template definition or use a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, As @T.C. said -

Unfortunately no. If you don't want the extra typing, put your function definitions inside the class definition, particularly for trivial-to-implement functions like `isEmpty()` or the default constructor.

Also, Macro can be used to avoid long redundant code i.e. `#define Generic template<typename T>`.